# Getting message 'a problem occurred while processing the request' when adding git project in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am facing an issue whenever I tried to connect my github repo using free style project in Jenkins. Getting the below error message

[image]

What could be possible solution to fix this issue ?

Comment: See if the Jenkins system logs at 'https://<yourjenkins.yourdomain.net>/log/all' provide any more information when you encounter this.